# SmartSheet-API: change the readwrite publish URL

Tags: java, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-java-sdk-v1

I am trying to change the URL for a smartsheet edit by anyone publication with the following code

```
    Sheet sheet = null;
    try {
        sheet = smartsheet.sheets().getSheet(sheetId, null);
    } catch (SmartsheetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        SheetPublish publish = new SheetPublish.PublishStatusBuilder().setReadOnlyFullEnabled(false).
                setReadOnlyLiteEnabled(false).setIcalEnabled(false).setReadWriteEnabled(true).build();
        publish.setReadWriteUrl(URL);
        smartsheet.sheets().updatePublishStatus(sheet.getId(), publish);
    } catch (SmartsheetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I run this I get an InvalidRequestException. I need to be able to change this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are trying to publish a sheet and get the URL or change the URL for a sheet that is already published. I will cover both topics.

### Publish Type

First you need to decide what type of publish you would like to do. Below is a short description of each of the publishing types. More info about publishing can be found [here](http://help.smartsheet.com/customer/portal/articles/522078-publishing-sheets).

> **setReadOnlyLiteEnabled**: Lightweight version of the sheet without row attachments or discussions.
>   **setReadOnlyFullEnabled**: Rich version of the sheet with the ability to download row attachments and discussions.
>
> **setReadWriteEnabled**: Rich version of sheet with the ability to edit cells and manage row attachments and discussions.
>
> **setIcalEnabled**: Add key dates from this sheet to your non-Smartsheet calendar

### Publish a sheet with the Java SDK

With your example code it looks like you were trying to publish a sheet with the setReadWriteEnabled type. So here is an example that accomplishes that and prints out the URL of where the sheet is published.

```
SheetPublish sheetPublish = new SheetPublish.PublishStatusBuilder().setIcalEnabled(false).setReadOnlyFullEnabled(false).
        setReadOnlyLiteEnabled(false).setReadWriteEnabled(true).build();
SheetPublish sheetPublishResult = smartsheet.sheets().updatePublishStatus(7298027523204996L, sheetPublish);
System.out.println(sheetPublishResult.getReadWriteUrl());
```

### Change published Sheet URL

Currently there is not an option to generate a new URL.

If you must remove access to the published sheet at a specific URL, then you can turn off the publish settings by setting the appropriate type to false (e.g. `setReadWriteEnabled(false)`).

The smartsheet API (which the Java SDK uses) documents what we can set when publishing a sheet at [this location](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#set-sheet-publish-status).

Copying the sheet to a new sheet and then publish the new sheet is another option. This would give you a new publish URL since this is a new sheet. This can be accomplished with code like the following

```
// Setup a sheet to copy
Sheet sheet = new Sheet();
sheet.setFromId(7298027523204996L);
// Copy the sheet
Sheet newSheet = smartsheet.sheets().createSheetFromExisting(sheet, EnumSet.allOf(ObjectInclusion.class));
// Setup what we will publish
SheetPublish sheetPublish = new SheetPublish.PublishStatusBuilder().setIcalEnabled(false).setReadOnlyFullEnabled(false).
        setReadOnlyLiteEnabled(false).setReadWriteEnabled(true).build();
// publish the new sheet
SheetPublish sheetPublishResult = smartsheet.sheets().updatePublishStatus(newSheet.getId(), sheetPublish);
System.out.println(sheetPublishResult.getReadWriteUrl());
```

Comment: Thank you! I do have another question about this though. Is there a way to create the copy in the same folder/workspace as the original? This code creates the new sheet in the "sheets" folder in Home.

Comment: Sure, take a look at: `smartsheet.sheets().createSheetInFolderFromExisting(...)`

Comment: With the API 2.0 Sheet newSheet = smartsheet.sheets().createSheetFromExisting(sheet, EnumSet.allOf(ObjectInclusion.class)); no longer works and I tried to use createSheetInFolderFromTemplate(folderId, sheet, null) and I received an error saying "effectiveAttachmentOptions" was of unexpected type. Did this change with the API 2.0? I am having trouble editing my code to work with the 2.0.

Comment: Notice that [smartsheet.sheets()](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/smartsheet-java-sdk/com/smartsheet/api/Smartsheet.html#sheets--) is deprecated, instead use [smartsheet.sheetResources()](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/smartsheet-java-sdk/com/smartsheet/api/Smartsheet.html#sheetResources--)

Comment: I am still getting the "effectiveAttachmentOptions" was of unexpected type error. I got the same error with a sheet that did not have any attachments.

Comment: Can you please post a new question on Stack Overlow with an example of the code you are using?